# Where would I add center-block to centre my content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Where would I add `center-block` to centre my content in my button coding & document coding?

**1**

```
<a href="#contact-me" target="_blank">
      <button id="linkbutton">Find out more about me</button>
      </a>
```

**2**

```
<p  style=" margin: 12px auto 6px auto; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,Sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: normal; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; -x-system-font: none; display: block;">   <a title="View CV on Scribd" href="https://www.scribd.com/document/343939101/CV?secret_password=HBP5kUMRKN6CbzPevWHo#from_embed"  style="text-decoration: underline;" >CV</a> by <a title="View Liam Docherty's profile on Scribd" href="https://www.scribd.com/user/353571708/Liam-Docherty#from_embed"  style="text-decoration: underline;" >Liam Docherty</a> on Scribd</p>
      <iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="https://www.scribd.com/embeds/343939101/content?start_page=1&view_mode=scroll&access_key=key-EnRdVJEYwlLWyOUwxs9h&show_recommendations=true" data-auto-height="false" data-aspect-ratio="0.7729220222793488" scrolling="no" id="doc_46092" width="600" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </body>
```

Comment: This is basically the same question you posted again. Start with some basic HTML tutorials first, and then move on to CSS.. Bootstrap will make more sense once you have a better understanding of HTML/CSS basics.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all of your HTML in a `<div class="container">`  That will force all of your information into a nice box. This is of course reliant on if you're using bootstrap. Hope that helped!